# Python requests при использовании прокси, запрос отправляется от фактического ip

Tags: python, requests, прокси

Когда мой скрипт получает 429 ошибку и я использую прокси то данная ошибка никуда не пропадает, то есть запрос происходит с фактического ip. Я беру прокси с сайта hidemy.name, подключаюсь к сайту avito.ru. В прокси-чекере проверил прокси и некоторые сервера работают. Вот мой код:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.avito.ru"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 
YaBrowser/21.2.2.102 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"}
list_proxy_https = ['167.99.252.218:3128', '49.128.186.178:8080', '159.8.114.37:80', '169.57.1.84:8123', '5.160.57.184:3128']
list_proxy_http = ['18.223.1.21:80', '20.195.17.90:3128', '167.99.252.218:3128', '23.227.38.15:80','93.114.65.150:80']
for i in range(0,5):
    proxies = {"https://":"https://"+list_proxy_https[i], "http://":"http://"+list_proxy_http[i]}
    res = requests.get(url, headers = headers, proxies = proxies, timeout = 2)
```

Я уже пробовал записывать в proxies {"https://":list_proxy_https[i]} но нечего не получалось. Так-же нашёл в гугле что эти сайты могут использовать заголовок x_forwarded_for, но как тогда обойти эту защиту если она есть?

Comment: Использовать анонимизирующий прокси, который не "светит" ip пользователя.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: пробовали менять user-agent?